# Why am I getting undefined symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceID?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

This is an iOS app that uses Firebase.

**If I comment out code that gets Firebase's instanceID tokens, then I'm able to compile and link.**

I installed Firebase with CocoaPods.  No errors at all, no warnings.  (Before `pod install` I did `pod update`.  So I got the latest Firebase.)

The reference comes from `AppDelegate.o`.  In `AppDelegate.swift` I have

`import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import GoogleUtilities`

I know you'll ask to see a lot more about the environment.  I'm not sure everything I should show you.  I'll edit the question as you request more information.

**UPDATE 1**: Here's something I also notice in the output window.

`<Warning>: 5.8.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000022] Firebase Analytics is not available. To add it, include Firebase/Core in the Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to the Link Build Phase`

But my Podfile looks just fine.  Here's my Podfile.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'XKCD' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for XKCD

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  target 'XKCDTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'XKCDUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

**UPDATE 2**: Here's what seems as a pretty relevant event.  I added Firebase/Database to my Podfile just to see if I could use the database.  I couldn't even compile the project with more linking errors, so I totally gave up on the task, removed Firebase/Database from my Podfile and said `pod install` to my shell once again to reflect my change of mind.  Here's what happened:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Removing FirebaseAuth
Removing FirebaseAuthInterop
Removing FirebaseDatabase
Removing GTMSessionFetcher
Removing leveldb-library
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase 5.11.0 (was 5.8.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 5.3.0 (was 5.1.2 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCore 5.1.6 (was 5.1.3 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID 3.3.0 (was 3.2.1 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing FirebaseMessaging 3.2.1 (was 3.1.2 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement 5.3.0 (was 5.1.2 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing GoogleUtilities 5.3.4 (was 5.2.3)
Using Protobuf (3.6.1)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 10 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `XKCD` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

I make no conclusions for the moment.  (Uncommenting the InstanceID code and trying to compile it again blows the same message about undefined symbol `_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceID`.  Commenting it out and recompiling runs the app just fine, though I still see that "Firebase Analytics is not available" message in the output window.)

Comment: Are you opening the xcworkspace versus the xcodeproj? Is that the only undefined symbol?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Definitely opening the xcworkspace.  This is the only undefined symbol.  (When I tried to compile this project for the first time, I had other undefined symbols which were related to the GoogleUtilities library.  All I had to do was "import GoogleUtilities" at my `AppDelegate.swift`.  But this one remains.)

Comment: Did you add Firebase to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries for your target's Build Phases like the error says?

Comment: @Dare, I'm using CocoaPods, so the only library I must have there is really `Pods_MYPROJECT.framework`.  (And it is as such.)  (Thanks!)